# Binding Dictionary<string,string> to Combobox in SL3

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, silverlight-3.0, selecteditem

I'm trying to do the following. 
I have a class:

```
public class TextField {
    public string TextType { get; set; }
}
```

in my View I created a list:

```
public TextFieldEditControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<string, string> lst = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        lst.Add("SingleLine", "Single line");
        lst.Add("MultiLine", "Multi-line");
        lst.Add("RichText", "Rich text");
        cmbTextType.ItemsSource = lst;
    }
```

in my XAML i have:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbTextType" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectionChanged="cmbTextType_SelectionChanged" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TextType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The problem is that when I check the value of the TextType property, it returns a string like that: "[SingleLine, Single line]" instead of just the Key. Where can I set it to return only the key for a Key/Value Pair?

Comment: I cannot see there any source code realted to TextField, so why do you define that class?

Comment: That's just a part of my class, I define it to set DataContext of my view to this class, and then I'm adding them to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your title you specified Silverlight 3, which unfortunately didn't have the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath properties that Anthony mentions.  This means that you need to do a nasty workaround to get it to work.  I discuss it here in this Silverlight 2 era article of mine, in a section titled "The ComboBox Nightmare": http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Application-Part-5.aspx.  It was a pain in Silverlight 2, and wasn't fixed until Silverlight 4.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Comment: Thanks, Chris! That is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find the source code for a value converter on that page. I have an idea about how to covert KeyValuePair to just Key, but I'm not sure how to convert it back from one string value. Could you please explain?

Comment: Hi Masha. There's a link to download the sample application with all the code on the page (near the top). Or just click here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/Storage/Sources/AdventureWorksLOB_Part5.zip :).

Comment: Oh, I found it. Sorry. Yes, I think I'll go with this solution, although it's way too much work than it would've been otherwise.. thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

Bind to the `SelectedValue` property instead of `SelectedItem` and specify `SelectedValuePath="Key"`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbTextType" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
   SelectionChanged="cmbTextType_SelectionChanged"
   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TextType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm getting the following error: Error 1 The property 'SelectedValue' does not exist on the type 'ComboBox' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: @Masha: Sorry missed the SL3 in your title, these were added in SL4 as Chris points out.

Comment: That's good to know for the future (when my company finally decides to upgrade :). Thanks a lot, Anthony!